# Make section line the highest line in beamer frame header

Tags: beamer

When I leave the square brackets after `\title` empty to remove the title from all subsequent frames, it still inserts the blank title line and tree branches for sections. I want

1. the title and title line to go away,
2. sections to appear as the highest level in the header, with no branches,
3. subsections to appear below sections, with branches.

Here is a MWE of my current setup:

```
\title[]
{My Slide Title}

\author[My Name]{My Name\\
My Dept\\
My College\\
My University\\
My Advisor}

% No navigation buttons
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Theme
\usetheme{Montpellier}

% Number slides with no totals
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber\strut\quad}

\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

%% Title frame 
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%% Frame: From here on out, I want no title or title line in the header, and for section 
%% to instead appear as the highest line in the header
\section{Presentation Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentation Outline}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Motivations
  \item Background
  \item A Framework for Domain Estimation  
  \item Patterns in Postfire Tree Cover 
  \item Methods for Model-assisted Estimation  
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine the `headline` of the theme template like this (code adapted from the original code in `beamerouterthemetree.sty`):

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}

\title{My Slide Title}

\author[My Name]{My Name\\
My Dept\\
My College\\
My University\\
My Advisor}

% No navigation buttons
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Theme
\usetheme{Montpellier}

% Number slides with no totals
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber\strut\quad}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\mode<presentation>{}
\begin{document}

%% Title frame 
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

%% Frame: From here on out, I want no title or title line in the header, and for section 
%% to instead appear as the highest line in the header
\section{Presentation Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentation Outline}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Motivations
  \item Background
  \item A Framework for Domain Estimation  
  \item Patterns in Postfire Tree Cover 
  \item Methods for Model-assisted Estimation  
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Example Subsection}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

You won't need to use `[]` to prevent printing the title then. I would suggest that you place the `\documentclass` first in your code, by the way.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Answer accepted.